# Using colour within fontographer 5

Tags: color, fontlab-fontographer

I have recently designed a logotype which needs to include the colours originally designed with in Illustrator. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Make sure to view our nice [Help Center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) to understand how best to use the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fontographer is for creating typefaces, which does not concern itself with colors. PostScript Level 3 typefaces may possibly include color information - you would need to read up on the specifications. But most of the type-world has moved on to the more flexible and widely supported OpenType which does not support "color".

Instead of viewing your logotype as a typeface or font, I would suggest approaching it as vector-based artwork and use tools like Illustrator, Affinity Designer, Sketch, Inkscape or Corel Draw to manipulate and adjust the artwork as you need it. Treating it as vector artwork and using tools for vector artwork would allow you adjust colors.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply! I have designed the type in Illustrator which uses colour. The logotype needs to be in colour as it is a client brief and it needs to be a working typeface. Could you recommend anything?

Comment: You can't create a typeface (font software) with color settings (as in each character could have its own color - ignoring bitmap fonts). See http://forum.fontlab.com/fontographer/create-a-color-font/.   This is a constraint of the medium and technology. Instead, take your Illustrator artwork and "typeset" the logotype using your artwork. Explain to the client the technical limitations that prevent them from having an editable, colored typeface.

Comment: Brilliant I have found something that I can use. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please note @Taylor-AshleyPycroft that type 3 fonts do not support colors directly only indirectly and that wont help much as hardly no program supports this.